# Согласование сложносоставных существительных

Tags: согласование

Вот что говорит [Розенталь](http://www.rosental-book.ru/styli_xliv.html).

> Части сложносоставных наименований согласуются в падеже и числе,
> например: *в письме-открытке, машиной-канавокопателем, на
> витринах-стендах*. То же при наличии числительных: *два торта-мороженых,
> три школы-интерната, четыре платья-халата* (**в этих примерах
> числительное одинаково сочетается с каждой частью сложного названия)**.
> В отдельных случаях вторая часть не согласуется: у *акулы-молот*.

С какой целью Розенталь даёт комментарий в скобках? Это просто пояснение для тех, кто сам не заметил? Или это как-то помогает нам применить правило в других случаях? Может, просто указание на то, что для других случаев правила не разработаны и нужно писать, как бог на душу положит? (Похоже, до сих пор все именно так и делают.)

У меня возникла сложность с согласованием слов типа *девочка-подросток, девушка-подросток, женщина-инструктор* и т.п. с числительным два.

Я попытался разобраться. Для начала поискал примеры в литературе.

> Там занимается упражнениями группа акробатов: толстый пожилой мужчина,
> женщина лет тридцати — тридцати пяти и две **девушки-подростка**. (А. Куприн) [В некоторых изданиях *две девушки-подростки*]
>
> Около огня сидели две **девушки-подростки**... (Д.Н. Мамин-Сибиряк)
>
> Знатных покойников сопровождали пятеро слуг — двое детей, две
> **девочки-подростка** и юноша. (Археология Украинской ССР, Наук. думка, 1986)
>
> Две **девочки-подростка** с куцыми косичками быстро взобрались на печь и с
> любопытством дикарей выглядывали оттуда. (Н. Островский)

И множество других подобных примеров. Оба варианта встречаются примерно одинаково часто у приличных авторов и в приличных изданиях. В трёх учебных пособиях по русскому языку я нашёл последнюю цитату из "Как закалялась сталь", но откорректированную (там "девочки-подростки"; и цитата эта упоминается по другому поводу).

Даже если это не оговорено правилами, просьба дать какой-то совет, исходя из личных предпочтений.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно это делается в три этапа.

1. Определяем склоняемость частей. Это , пожалуй, самое сложное. Но есть такая шпаргалка с грамоты.ру. или словари.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/63-rubric-93

В вашем примере оба слова склоняются. Две девушки, два подростка.

2. Определяем род слржного слова. По смыслу. Девушки — основное слово, оно имеет более общий смысл. Подростки — дополнительная информация о возрасте. Девушки -подростки — существительное женского рода.
   Хотела дать ссылку на "Культуру речи", там это описывается, но не получилось.
3. Согласовываем числительное с существительным. Две девушки-подростка.

Другие примеры: два счёта-фактуры, два луна-парка, две рыбы-меч две плащ-палатки и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваша логика меня убеждает, что из двух вариантов Ваш выбор предпочтительнее. Я проголосовал за ответ, но не принял его по одной причине: я потом нашёл на Грамоте (вопрос 296113) рекомендацию не употреблять такие конструкции и я лично хотел бы, чтобы эта рекомендация получила максимальную известность и со временем вошла в правила.

Comment: Кресло-качалка, секретарь-машинистка, счёт-фактура, диван -кровать, музей -квартира ( они сами пишут, что таких слов более тысячи). Избежать употребления? Попробуйте.

Comment: Трудности у лингвистов вызывают слова, у которых первая часть женского рода, а вторая — мужского. Таких меньше тысячи и их в склонении с этими числительными можно избегать. Я говорил выше, что в "Трудных вопросах синтаксиса и пунктуации" (Гужва Ф.К.) говорится, что правильно "две девочки-подростки", в пособии "Русский язык. Синтаксис" (А.С.Бедняков) — тоже. Я не нашёл ни одного учебника, в котором рекомендовали бы Ваш вариант. Хотя Ваш мне представляется логичным, а авторы этих учебников вообще не предлагают никакой логики. Что лучше: подчиниться правилам или писать по собственной логике?

Comment: Это по Розенталю , см Ваш первый абзац, я тут ни при чём.

Comment: Я (и упомянутые лингвисты) толкуют этот пункт Розенталя иначе.

Comment: Мне как-то дико сочетание "две девочки -подростки ", это значит, что одна девочка-подростка.

Comment: Согласен. Более того, если бы всем лингвистам это сочетание казалось таким же диким, тогда такого вопроса просто ни у кого не возникало бы. Вот Вам ещё пример. Ни в Нацкорпусе, ни в гугло-книгах ни разу не встречается сочетание "две девочки-близнеца". А "две девочки-близнецы" встречается много раз, даже в работах лингвистов и филологов. Поэтому нужно выбирать: либо всех их переубедить, либо согласиться с ними, либо как я предлагал выше — каждый пишет как бог на душу положит. Поэтому я считаю наиболее правильным (из реалистичных) вариантом решения "избегать".